# Treatment effect on categorical dependent variable - changed to numeric

Tags: r, categorical-data, survival

I conducted an experiment where I tested the effect of copper on irrigation dripper blockage.
I had dripper types "copper" and "normal" and once a week I measured whether they are working (1) or not (0).
All the drippers started working (1) and all of them were blocked (0) by the end of the experiment.
**I need to analyze if there was a significant effect of the type and when.**
I also suspect that some type of debris might block the drippers based on their proximity to the water source so I added their position to the data.
A sample of the data:

```
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  Date                Lateral Position `Distance (m)` Type   Working
  <dttm>              <fct>   <fct>             <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  
1 2022-08-10 00:00:00 1       1                   0.7 Normal 1      
2 2022-08-10 00:00:00 1       2                   1.2 Normal 1      
3 2022-08-10 00:00:00 1       3                   1.7 Copper 1      
4 2022-08-10 00:00:00 1       4                   2.2 Copper 1      
5 2022-08-10 00:00:00 1       5                   2.7 Copper 1      
6 2022-08-10 00:00:00 2       1                   0.9 Normal 1  
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1660089600, 1660089600, 1660089600, 
1660089600, 1660089600, 1660089600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Lateral = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Position = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    `Distance (m)` = c(0.7, 1.2, 1.7, 2.2, 2.7, 0.9), Type = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Copper", "Normal"), class = "factor"), 
    Working = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So I calculated the days each dripper worked (days_worked) as suggested by @sashahafner. The new dataframe:
`structure(list(id = 1:6, days_worked = c(15, 25, 15, 21, 25,  25), last_date = structure(c(1661385600, 1662249600, 1661385600,  1661904000, 1662249600, 1662249600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",  "POSIXt")), lateral = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("1",  "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), position = structure(c(1L,  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"),  type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Copper",  "Normal"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))`
I want to check whether the position (lateral and position columns) has an effect and if the type has  an effect on the days_worked.

What kind of test should I use?
Any pointers as to what to read or how to solve this will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why not simply calculate how many weeks the drippers worked before becoming blocked and use that as your response variable? Of course you have to think about an appropriate error distribution but even a simple transformation could work, and allow you to use `lm()` or a wrapper.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try and see if it gives the results I'm after. I don't think I understand the part about error distribution. Also, why would I need to use lm()? I'm trying to show difference between treatments not predict time to blocked drippers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a type of [survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis): you have an event and you want to know if some treatment (with other variables taken into account) is associated with the time to the event. Your initial data format could have been appropriate for formal survival analysis.

In this case, with all cases eventually having the event, survival analysis can be just a simple linear regression (via `lm()` in R) of time-to-event against your set of predictor variables, as @sashahafner suggested in a comment. That would evaluate the association between time-to-event and `treatment` with the other predictors taken into account. You could extend that to assess the possibility that the effect of `treatment` depends on the values of the other variables, by adding interaction terms among them.

More generally, you would need to take "censoring" into account: for example, it would be "right censoring" if some cases never developed the block before the end of your study so you only had a lower limit to the time-to-event. There is one caution related to survival analysis that you should consider: if you only evaluated blockage "once a week" but your time-to-event values are on the order of 20 days, you don't really have precise time-to-blockage data, just times to when you *found* the blockage. That's called "[interval censoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interval-censoring)"; the link points to over 90 questions about that on this site, with more available via a text search for "interval censor*".

*Example*

Here's some sample data, with `type=copper` taking 10 days longer to block on average and each extra unit of `dist` leading to 1 day faster to block. Add in some random error with a standard deviation of 3 days. Also, provide for a situation when observations stopped at 35 days so longer event times are right censored.

```
pipeData <- expand.grid(dist=1:5,type=c(rep("normal",4),rep("copper",4)))
set.seed(101)
pipeData[,"blockedTime"] <- 30 - pipeData$dist + 10*(pipeData$type=="copper") +rnorm(40,0,3)
pipeData[,"event"] <- as.numeric(pipeData$blockedTime<35)
pipeData[,"censTime"] <- pipeData$blockedTime
pipeData[pipeData$event==0,"censTime"] <- 35
```

If there are no censored event times, this is nicely handled by a simple linear model with both `type` and `dist` as predictors.

```
summary(lm(blockedTime~type+dist,data=pipeData))
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = blockedTime ~ type + dist, data = pipeData)
# 
# Residuals:
#    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
# -6.008 -1.791  0.395  1.913  4.575 
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  30.2971     1.1233   26.97  < 2e-16 ***
# typecopper   10.2769     0.8812   11.66  5.9e-14 ***
# dist         -1.1963     0.3115   -3.84 0.000465 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 2.787 on 37 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.8029,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7923 
# F-statistic: 75.38 on 2 and 37 DF,  p-value: 8.908e-14
```

The coefficient for `typecopper` is the estimated difference in days to blockage between `normal` and `copper`, at the same value of `dist`. The "significance" of that coefficient represents the "significance" of `type`. The coefficient for `dist` is the change in number of days to blockage per unit of `dist`.

If there is right censoring, you can use survival analysis. For example:

```
library(survival)   
summary(coxph(Surv(censTime,event)~type+dist,data=pipeData))
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(censTime, event) ~ type + dist, data = pipeData)
# 
#   n= 40, number of events= 24 
# 
#                coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
# typecopper -3.92281   0.01979  0.74573 -5.260 1.44e-07 ***
# dist        0.49910   1.64724  0.17492  2.853  0.00433 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
#            exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
# typecopper   0.01979    50.5425  0.004588   0.08533
# dist         1.64724     0.6071  1.169131   2.32086
# 
# Concordance= 0.87  (se = 0.024 )
# Likelihood ratio test= 47.21  on 2 df,   p=6e-11
# Wald test            = 28.35  on 2 df,   p=7e-07
# Score (logrank) test = 46  on 2 df,   p=1e-10
```

Here, the coefficients are the log-hazard differences associated with `type` and `dist`. The negative coefficient for `typecopper` means that the hazard of blockage is lower for `copper` than for the reference `normal`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll start reading about survival analysis. The blockage checking interval was actually determined by when we had time to go and check the drippers considering that a week difference between treatments isn't meaningful in RL and so a "precise" time can be a week. What I don't understand is how `lm()` can be used to determine significant difference between the treatments?

Comment: @sdabach I've added examples showing how `lm()` can be used if there's no censoring, and `coxph()` can be used if there is.

Comment: Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 0):

In accord with the suggestion above, whatever the time granularity you used to check the dripper (day, week, month) I would use that as the basis, used the difference between the deployment date and the date of failure as you test variable.

Then you could use a straight up Z-Test or T-Test to calculate if there is a difference between the two, dependent on how many observations you had. The important thing is that all the drippers should have received the same treatment for this to be meaningful.

EDIT:

To clarify, the reason that you use a t-test or z-test is because you were comparing treatments, the difference between the copper and the regular drippers. The assumption is that all else is held constant.

You can do other types of analysis, such as survival.

But the comparison of two samples with different treatments is asking are these two samples from the same population, based on this one factor, time to failure?

If they are essentially the same then they difference in dripper's material will have no affect on the mean length of time until failure.

Comment: Thank you too. Doesn't the number of observations depend on variability? Can the Z or T tests consider several variables (the position)? or should I use them only if I find the position has no effect?

Comment: The number of observations depend on your experimental design. How many of each material do you have? If both groups are greater than 30 you should use the Z-test, if less than 30 or not normally distributed, use the t-test (in reality most people us the t-test either way)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to eliminate the position effect in the experiment itself.